# How to creating expanding race track and keep the edges uniformed

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms, path, curve-modifier

im trying to create this dynamic path where the path is expending in the middle and going back to the same width. i tried using scale but the borders are also scaling and creating not clean path
[image]

in general the scaling method does not look natural

[image]